# Java, Exception when trying to deserialize object, problems catching

Tags: java, object, exception, serialization, load

I have a program that needs to load data at launch. The data comes from a serialized object. I have a method `loadData()`, which is called upon construction of the `Data` class. Sometimes, (I.e. after a loss of saveData, or on first program launch on a new system), the file can be empty. (The file will exist though, the method ensures that).

When I try to run the program, I recieve an EOFException. So, in the method, I try to catch it, and just print a line to the console explaining what happened and return to the caller of the method. (so, upon return, the program will think `loadData()` is complete and has returned. However, it still crashes throwing the exception without printing a line to the console or anything. It is like it is totally ignoring the catch I have in place.

CODE:

```
protected void loadData()
{
    // Gets/creates file object.
    saveFileObject = new File("savedata.ser");

    if(!saveFileObject.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            saveFileObject.createNewFile();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Uh oh...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // Create file input stream
    try
    {
    fileIn = new FileInputStream(saveFileObject);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Create object input stream
    try
    {
    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Try to deserialize
    try
    {
        parts = (ArrayList<Part>)inputStream.readObject();
    }
    catch(EOFException e)
    {
        System.out.println("EOFException thrown! Attempting to recover!");
        return;
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // close input stream
    try
    {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Can you give your console log of exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing your code like :

```
protected void loadData() {
    // Gets/creates file object.
    saveFileObject = new File("savedata.ser");


    try {
        if (!saveFileObject.exists()) {
            saveFileObject.createNewFile();
        }
        // Create file input stream
        fileIn = new FileInputStream(saveFileObject);

        // Create object input stream
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

        // Try to deserialize
        parts = (ArrayList<Part>) inputStream.readObject();

        // close input stream
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        System.out.println("EOFException thrown! Attempting to recover!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Uh oh...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also note that `EOFException` is a sub-class of `IOException`

Comment: This answer was almost useless (albeit informative), except for that last line. Thanks mate, fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

How about making one try and then making catches respectively like [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/putItTogether.html)?

Comment: While this is fine, and I do intend to do this at some point, this in no way answers my question.

Comment: So if you are catching exception and it doesn't catch maybe it occurs in other try?

Comment: Considering NetBeans whines when I don't catch it, I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: In other tries you catch IOExcpetion which catches also EOFException. Try to copy your EOFException catch onto every try in first place and see if this works.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but why wouldn't the catch default to the more specific `EOFException`, or failing that, at least to the next one in line? Is there any way I can change this behavior? (Also, you are correct, doing that did work)